# Bootrap 4 - Text on Screen left beside an image ... on Smartphone Text under the image

Tags: html, css, web, bootstrap-4, media-queries

With Bootstrap 4 (probably also with all other versions) how do I ensure that I have the text on the screen to the left of the image and that the image is above the text on the smartphone?

That's my source Code:

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">Text</div>
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">Image</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">Image</div>
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">Text</div>
</div>
</div>
```

`flex-direction: row-reverse` did not work here.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! You could perhaps include a screenshot to explain what you are trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 0):

Use `.order` classes to position the image:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-12">Text</div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-12 order-first">Image</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-12 order-first">Image</div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-12">Text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/grid/#order-classes

You can also add them depending on the width with the usual xs, sm, md, lg & xl tags, e.g. `.order-md-first`

https://jsfiddle.net/Sirence/cx6k1048/4/

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to add two classes to the two outer div with class **row**. Then use media Queries to hide div depending on the screen size, So your code should be like this.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row desktopView">
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">Text</div>
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">Image</div>
</div>
<div class="row mobileView">
<div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">Image</div>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">Text</div>
</div>
</div>


@media (max-width: 576px) {
.desktopView {
  display: none;
}
.mobileview {
  display: block;
}
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
.mobileview {
  display: none;
}
}
```

You hide first the mobile div on desktop view and show it on mobile view.
Hope that help @davideos477

Answer (score 0):

- If you are using `bootstrap-4` and need `100%` width on mobile so don't need to include `col-xs` or `sm` classes.
- And `bootstrap-4` is using `flexbox`. With the help of flexbox you can easily order to your div on different screen.
- For bootstrap ordering you can use `order-*` class. And `order` class is also with according to screen like: `order-sm-*` or `order-md-*`
- Bootstrap 4 grid example: [Bootstrap 4 Grid example](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_grid_system.asp)
- For understanding about flexbox ordering. Please check [Flexbox Ordering](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_flex-order-responsive)

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-12">Text</div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-12">Image</div>
     </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-12">Image</div>
        <div class="ccol-md-6 col-12">Text</div>
    </div>
</div>
```